# Order ArrayList by attribute object the ArrayList holds?

Tags: c#

How do I order an ArrayList of objects by one of the objects attributes?

Answer (score 4):

ArrayList is somewhat deprecated. We use the generic [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class now.*

You can sort a List<T> in-place using [List<T>.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=VS.100).aspx):

```
List<Person> persons = // ...

persons.Sort((a, b) => string.Compare(a.Name, b.Name));
```

or create a new List<T> using LINQ's [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx):

```
List<Person> persons = // ...

List<Person> sortedPersons = persons.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

*(* Unless you're stuck with .NET Framework 1.1)*

Comment: Hey ive tried your first suggestion and its telling me i need to use a delegate type? :s

Comment: I've doublechecked it and it works here. What framework version do you use? Can you post your code? What's the exact error message you get?

Comment: He's talking about ArrayList.  Lambdas requires him to catch up with 3 updates and a whole bunch of reading.  Lost cause, really.

Comment: @Tom: Make sure you are using Visual Studio 2008 or 2010.  This will not work in 2005.  @Hans: More than likely he is coming from Java..

Comment: Brilliant, concise and Works!

Answer (score 2):

As dtb explained, you should probably use a generic `List<T>` than an untyped `ArrayList` unless you're using a pre 2.0 version of .NET.

If you really want to do it with an `ArrayList`, there are two way of doing it :

- if the elements of the collection implement `IComparable`, just use the `Sort` method with no arguments :

  ```
  arrayList.Sort();
  ```
- otherwise, you need to create a custom comparer by implementing the `IComparer` interface :

  ```
  public class PersonComparer : IComparer
  {
      public int Compare(object a, object b)
      {
          Person pa = a as Person;
          Person pb = b as Person;
          if (pa == pb) return 0;
          if (pa == null) return -1;
          if (pb == null) return 1;
          return string.Compare(pa.Name, pb.Name);
      }
  }

  ...

  arrayList.Sort(new PersonComparer());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to sort an array you need to compare it with a specific element of it.
Suppose you have a List of array called Client and Client has clientID
Now you want to sort it. Your code should be

```
Client.Sort(a, b) => string.Compare(a.clientID.ToString(), b.clientID.ToString()));
```